# Migrating from ASP.NET MVC 3 to ASP.NET Identity 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity

We are wondering what is the best migration path for an ASP.NET MVC 3 project to Identity 2.0

Our current project features the ASP.NET membership with custom password reset implementation.

The migration requirements are the following:

- We want to switch to Bootstrap without recycling anything of the current website style/layout
- We want - obviously - to maintain the thousand membership users currently in the database

Should we:

1. Migrate the authentication logic first, then create a new VS2013 project and copy over controllers and views for a clean Bootstrap interface
2. Migrate to ASP.NET 4.0 first, than to ASP.NET Identity 2.0, then create a new VS2013 project and copy over controllers and views for a clean Bootstrap interface
3. Create a new VS2013 project, copy over controllers and views then try to implement new authentication?
4. Migrate to ASP.NET 5.0 first, than to ASP.NET Identity 2.0, then create a new VS2013 project and copy over controllers and views for a clean Bootstrap interface

Thanks.

Comment: Personally I would go with the migration mentioned in point 2. Is there any reason why you don't directly migrate to ASP.NET MVC 5?

Comment: Forgot to mention it... for ASP.NET Identity 2.0 I gave it for granted. I'll edit the question...

Comment: Alright, after your update point 4 seems better to me. Is there a reason why you want to copy & paste your controllers and views?

Comment: Yes, to have a brand new Bootstrap style/layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would follow this [tutorial which walks you through the steps to migrate from ASP.NET Membership to ASP.NET Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/migrations/migrating-an-existing-website-from-sql-membership-to-aspnet-identity).  The project basically has you open the old project in VS 2013, which was what I would do instead of copying.  I would also [upgrade to MVC 5 using NuGet](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2) and you can add Bootstrap to your project as well using NuGet. You will have to modify your views to use the Bootstrap classes and include the Bootstrap CSS in your views or layout/master view.